# Solving Line Integral When Given Vector and Bounds

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

I've been stuck on this problem for a while now. I have to evaluate the line integral below:

$\int_{C}^{}(x+4 \sqrt{y}) ds \\ C: \vec{r}^{} (t)=t\vec{i}^{} + t\vec{j}^{} \\ 0\leq t \leq 1 $

What I tried to do is:

$ \\x=t, y=t \\ 
\int_{C}^{}(x+4 \sqrt{y}) ds = \int_{0}^{1}(t+4 \sqrt{t})(\sqrt{(\frac{dx}{dt})^2 + (\frac{dy}{dt})^2} dt= \int_{0}^{1}(t+4 \sqrt{t})(\sqrt{1+1})dt = Undefined $

I don't understand where I've gone wrong in my solution and would greatly appreciate some help.

Comment: Consider that $ds=\sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2}dt$ and integrate

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I actually did do that, when solving the problem. I just wrote it incorrectly when typing up the question. Regardless, I am still getting the incorrect answer.

Comment: What is the answer given and wht is your result?

Comment: I get an undefined answer (divide by zero). The given answer is $\frac{19\sqrt{2}}{6}$

Comment: The value of the integral you wrote is exactly [the given answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+between+0+and+1+of+sqrt(2)(x%2B4sqrt(x))). The primitive has no any division by zero.

Comment: Hello, after an hour, I finally figured out that I was repeatedly making a mistake while integrating. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You are welcome.